# I have model values and wanted to display in @Html.DropDownList or @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I'm new to razor view pages.
I have a model where I get the list values and wanted to display it on the view, using either @Html.DropDownListFor/ @Html.DropDownList, someone please help me with a code snippet.
I have the picture of the model (attached).

Since I don't have much idea on Razor, I ended up having html select tag and use jquery to get the data, but the problem is, I need to post the updated model to mvc controller.

```html
public class CountryViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string CountryCodeISO3 { get; set; }
        public string CountryCodeISO2 { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: public IEnumerable<CountryViewModel> Countries { get; set; }

Does it need to be List<CountryViewModel> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (haven't tested it)

Add a property in your model

```
public List<SelectListItem> Countries { get; set; }
```

Get the property values

```
List<SelectListItem> Countries = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var item in _db.Countries)
                    {
                        Countries.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = item.CountryName,
                            Value = item.Id.ToString()
                        });
                    }
```

In your view

```
<select class="form-control" id="countryId">
        <option selected="selected" value="-1"></option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Countries)
        {
            <option value="@item.Value">@item.Text</option>
        }
    </select>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I thought about the solution you provided, but the thing is I need to have 3 properties from the countryViewModel, in order to implement my business logic, if I use SelectListItem I can use only 2 properties.